# Get clicked cell from headertable in bodytable

Tags: events, gwt, tableview

I'm trying to get the clicked cell in a headertable to do sorting, but I want to handle this in another class, the class that implements the table. If I write out the cell in the headertable class is prints the right cell id, but when adding the clickhandler to the implementing class the id is always 0.

Example:

```
public class CustomerDetailsHoldingsTable extends SimpleTable<Holding> 
                                                  implements ClickHandler {

  TableDataSource<Holding> ds;

  Public CustomerDetailsHoldingsTable () {
    this.headerTable = new HeaderTable();
    this.headerTable.addClickHandler(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    GWT.log("Clicked cell with id" + 
             getCellForEvent(event).getCellIndex());
  }


  public class HeaderTable extends Grid { 
    ...
    ...
  }
```

The GWT.log line always prints 0 regardless what cell is clicked in the headertable. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to invoke `getCellForEvent` on your grid object, like so:

```
@Override
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    GWT.log("Clicked cell with id" + 
             this.headerTable.getCellForEvent(event).getCellIndex());
  }
```

From the [docs](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLTable.html#getCellForEvent%28com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent%29):

> Given a click event, return the Cell
>   that was clicked, or null if the event
>   did not hit this table. The cell can
>   also be null if the click event does
>   not occur on a specific cell.

Comment: it was the this.headerTable that was missing... Thanks.

Comment: Andreas, glad I could help. A piece of friendly advice, though: If my answer was the answer that helped you, you should mark it as accepted, to let other people know that this is the way to solve this issue. From your profile I see you haven't marked many of your answers as accepted, and this may make it a bit problematic for you if you want people to answer your questions in the future.